# Mysql Query combine two colums and get unique values of both

Tags: mysql, sql

I just can't figure out how to do the following.

**What I have**

... is a mysql table "mails" like:

```
id | sender | recipient | date                 | content | read
---------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 3      | 2         | 2016-07-29 09:04:21  | hello   | 1
2  | 2      | 3         | 2016-07-29 09:14:21  | hello   | 1
3  | 1      | 2         | 2016-07-29 09:24:21  | hello   | 1
4  | 1      | 3         | 2016-07-29 09:34:21  | hello   | 0
5  | 1      | 1         | 2016-07-29 09:44:21  | hello   | 1
6  | 3      | 1         | 2016-07-29 09:54:21  | hello   | 0
7  | 1      | 1         | 2016-07-29 09:56:21  | hello   | 1
8  | 1      | 3         | 2016-07-29 09:58:21  | hello   | 0
9  | 2      | 2         | 2016-07-29 09:59:21  | hello   | 0
```

**What I need**

... is to get an overview of the latest chatpartners for one person, like the user with id `1` (the user can also send messages to himself) like

```
date                | partner
2016-07-29 09:58:21 | 3
2016-07-29 09:56:21 | 1
2016-07-29 09:24:21 | 2
```

No matter if the user is recipient or sender and no matter how many messages have been send or received. (I included the date column in the example output to clarify I need them sorted by date DESC, it does not need to be included in the final result)

**What I tried**

```
SELECT DISTINCT sender,recipient
FROM mails
WHERE recipient=1 OR sender=1
ORDER BY date DESC
```

but of course it does not combine the two columns. Output is

```
sender | recipient
1      | 3
1      | 1
3      | 1
1      | 2
```

If I add `GROUP BY sender` it does not display the mails where user 1 is only recipient.

I also tried the following

```
SELECT
    max(date) as d,
    CONCAT(greatest(sender,recipient),"_",least(sender,recipient)) AS p
FROM mails
WHERE recipient=1 OR sender=1
GROUP BY p ORDER BY d DESC
```

which, for example, gives

```
d                   | p
2016-07-29 09:58:21 | 3_1
2016-07-29 09:56:21 | 1_1
2016-07-29 09:24:21 | 2_1
```

What seems to be great, I can only take the first id shown ...
but when I look for user id 2, it gives

```
d                   | p
2016-07-29 09:59:21 | 2_2
2016-07-29 09:24:21 | 2_1
2016-07-29 09:14:21 | 3_2
```

... so it is unclear if the first or second id is the partner's id.

**Result**

I'm kind of desperate. Any help would be great.

Comment: Post the expected output

Comment: Huh? What I expect can be seen at the "what i need" section. I just mentioned the date col is not a must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want an aggregation like this:

```
select max(date) as date,
       (case when m.recipient = 1 then m.sender else m.recipient end) as partner
from mails
where 1 in (m.recipient, m.sender)
group by (case when m.recipient = 1 then m.sender else m.recipient end)
order by max(date);
```

Comment: Works like a charm after I added `from mails m` and `DESC` at the and :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is where 1 in (m.recipient, m.sender)  and (m.recipient =1 or m.sender =1)  are same ?

Comment: @rocks . . . They are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use a sub query to get max date for each `recipient`, then join itself:

```
select m.`recipient` as partner, m.`date`
from mails m
join (
    select max(`date`) as `date`, `recipient`
    from mails
    where sender = '1'
    group by `recipient`
) t
on m.`date` = t.`date` and m.`recipient` = t.`recipient`
where m.sender = '1'
order by m.`date` desc
```

[<kbd>**Demo Here**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ecb8/2)

Comment: I ran the query but unfortunately it does not return the partners where 1 is only recipient and never the sender :(